# How to use the command "rename" on subdirectories as well

Tags: command-line, rename

There is an answer that is very useful to me in this thread about renaming folders with trailing whitespaces:
[Remove Leading or Trailing Space(s) in File or Folder Names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668088/remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-file-or-folder-names)

What I can't figure out how I can change the following command so that it also changes the names in subfolders.

> rename -n 's/ *$//' *

I obviously already tried to check this myself with "rename -h" but I can;t see the solution.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Chris

Comment: Or just use the `mv` command: https://askubuntu.com/a/210174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just need to enable the `globstar` [option of the bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#:%7E:text=2%20The%20Shopt%20Builtin,change%20additional%20shell%20optional%20behavior.&text=Toggle%20the%20values%20of%20settings,(see%20The%20Set%20Builtin).) then use `**/*` instead of `*`:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/ *$//' **/*
```

- where `-n` option is dry run.

Comment: Although note that this will (at least attempt to) rename the *first* occurrence of `foo` wherever it appears in the path (not necessarily in the file name). For the OP's anchored pattern ` *$` that shouldn't be an issue of course.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. The only thing to mention is that if there are folders with a space in the end of the name in lower subdirectories as well, that then the command needs to be replicated until all have been renamed.

Comment: Hi, @steeldriver, thanks for the comment! My focus here was the globstar option rather than the rename command.

Comment: Thank you again pa4080 and also steeldriver. steeldriver, I just realised what you mentioned in your comment myself. Is there a way to avoid this by using a different OP? I guess the capabilities are limited by the usage of "rename" and next would be to use a small script?

Comment: @StackChrisChris, if you want to ping someone by your comment you need to use `@` before its nickname. By the way pm-b's answer is also worth.

Answer (score 4):

If your subfolders as well as files may end with trailing spaces (as discussed in comments), then you will need to process the directory tree *depth first*<sup>1</sup>. You can do this with the `find` command:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename -n 's/ *$//' {} +
```

You can replace `.` (current directory) with a specific starting directory `path/to/dir`.

The use of `-execdir` rather than `-exec` ensures that the replacement is only applied to the file or directory name (rather than the whole path), so it's safe even when the regex pattern isn't anchored to the filename.

---

<sup>1</sup>. otherwise it will *look* OK when testing with `-n` but will likely fail when applied for real, since it will attempt to rename files in directories whose names have already been changed

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver ! This is really interesting.

Comment: this works super. If I may ask, why are the expressions '{} +' required after the rename command? Is this realted to the find command or to the rename command or to the execdir command?

Comment: @StackChrisChris the `{}` is used by `find` as a placeholder representing each of the files that it finds. The `+` at the end tells `-execdir` (or `-exec`) to run the command on as many files as possible each time (more efficient) instead of once for each file. See for example [What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command)

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. Actually the execution of the command with -n gives "'FolderBad1 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad1'" but without -n gives an error "Can't rename 'FolderBad1 ' to 'FolderBad1': No such file or directory". This is far beyond the question that I initially asked anyways, so just for your information, please :-)

Comment: @StackChrisChris I can't reproduce that behavior - you should probably ask a separate question about that, with a testable example

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver - I will do that

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at your use of the `rename` command. I changed it to match trailing spaces for files with or without an extension:

```
rename -n 's/( +?)(?=\.[^.]*$|$)//' *
```

Then to act on all files and files in subfolders, you can use the `find` command to find all files or directories in a certain path

```
find . -type f 
find . -type d
```

and use the `-exec` subcommand of find to operate on those files or directories. Place the rename command after the `exec` subcommand. For example:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/( +)(?=\.[^.]*$|$)//' {} +
```

Comment: Thank you also @pm-b ! I learned something today :-)