# Use command "rename" on nested folders with trailing whitespaces

Tags: command-line, rename

I received great help in this thread about using command "rename" on folders with trailing whitespaces that are also in subdirectories.
[How to use the command "rename" on subdirectories as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287359/how-to-use-the-command-rename-on-subdirectories-as-well/1287380?noredirect=1#comment2185109_1287380)

Thanks again @pa4080 and @steeldriver and @pm-b

In general the solution requires to be executed several times, when folders with trailing whitespaces that are also *nested* in subdirectories

When I am using a proposed solution that was supposed to not require to execute the command several times but to do this automatically, I get an error message.

I was asked to post this question in a new thread. So here I go.

Command:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename -n 's/ *$//' {} +
```

File Structure ("Good" means no whitespace at end, "Bad" means whitespace at end:

```
|-FolderBad1 
  |  |-FolderGood1
  |  |-FolderBad2 
  |  |  |-FolderBad3 
  |-FolderGood
  |  |-Folder Good2
  |  |  |-FolderGood3
  |  |  |  |-FolderGood4
  |  |  |  |  |-FolderBad4 
  |  |  |  |  |-FolderBad5
```

Dry-Run (flag -n) gives this output as expected:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename -n 's/ *$//' {} +
'FolderBad3 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad3'
'FolderBad2 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad2'
'FolderBad1 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad1'
'FolderBad5 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad5'
'FolderBad4 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad4'
```

Removing -n flag gives this error message:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename 's/ *$//' {} +
Can't rename 'FolderBad3 ' to 'FolderBad3': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad2 ' to 'FolderBad2': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad5 ' to 'FolderBad5': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad4 ' to 'FolderBad4': No such file or directory
```

Running Dry-run again now:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename -n 's/ *$//' {} +
'FolderBad3 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad3'
'FolderBad2 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad2'
'FolderBad5 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad5'
'FolderBad4 ' would be renamed to 'FolderBad4'
```

Rerunning the command without -n gives the same error message:

```
find . -depth -name '* ' -execdir rename 's/ *$//' {} +
Can't rename 'FolderBad3 ' to 'FolderBad3': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad2 ' to 'FolderBad2': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad5 ' to 'FolderBad5': No such file or directory
Can't rename 'FolderBad4 ' to 'FolderBad4': No such file or directory
```

So just the FolderBad1 was renamed but none of the other "Bad" folders in the subdirectories.
So maybe it's the a similar question that I asked before already, how this command is applied to subdirectories.

Lots og text, I hope this clarified it.

Greetings, Chris

Comment: The `-n` output format is different from what I'd expect for the current Perl-based `rename` command - can you add the outputs of `type -a rename` and `rename --version`? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Looking at your results more closely, it seems like it *does* rename `FolderBad1`, but does so first (defying the `-depth` directive). Can you add `find --version` as well?